# How to mock object of frontend bundled with webpack? (sinon, selenium, webpack)

Tags: javascript, selenium, mocha.js, webpack, sinon

I need test some behavior (by selenium) of frontend side which is bundled by webpack. I need to mock one object (on browser side|frontend side) for that test, how can I do it?